# Helm cannot upgrade chart - Change service from NodePort to ClusterIP?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to edit services created via helm chart and when changing from NodePort to ClusterIP I get this error

```sh
The Service "<name>" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Fordbidden: may not be used when 'type' is 'ClusterIP'
```

I've seen solutions from other people where they just run `kubectl apply -f service.yaml --force` - but I'm not using kubectl but helm to do it - any thoughts ? If it was just one service I would just update/re-deploy manually but there are xx of them.

Comment: Show the content of service.yaml?

Comment: I found a guide for his exact question https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSHTQ/omnibus/helms/all_helms/wip/reference/hlm_upgrading_service_type_change.html

Comment: what's inside service doesn't matter ther's just Port TargetPort and Type - I didn't hardcode any nodeport port. And all Is done is changed type from ClusterIP to NodePort

Comment: Since you found an answer for your question (not the desired answer but a realistic answer) I suggest you to post as an answer the workaround you decided to go with in order to help others with similar issues.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer to my exact question in here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSHTQ/omnibus/helms/all_helms/wip/reference/hlm_upgrading_service_type_change.html

In short they suggest either to:

---

There are three methods you can use to avoid the service conversion issue above. You will only need to perform one of these methods:

- Method 1: Installing the new version of the helm chart with a different release name and update all clients to point to the new probe service endpoint if required. Then delete the old release. This is the recommended method but requires a re-configuration on the client side.
- Method 2: Manually changing the service type using kubectl edit svc. This method requires more manual steps but preserves the current service name and previous revisions of the helm chart. After performing this workaround, users should be able to perform a helm upgrade.
- Method 3: Deleting and purging the existing helm release, and then install the new version of helm chart with the same release name.